# Leveling System does not work

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to make **leveling system**, but currently "level up" does not work. I'm trying to check if a player has more kills than he need to level up when joining the server.

The problem is, I have 501 kills and I need 500 kills to level up, but nothing happens when I join my server. How to fix it?

**Code**

```
int kills = plugin.getConfig().getInt("Database."+player.getName()+".Level");
int basicexp = 5;
int incremento = 20;
int level = plugin.getConfig().getInt("Database."+player.getName()+".Level");
int exp = (basicexp * level) + (incremento * level);
int one = 1;
int nextlevel = level + one;
if (kills >= exp) {
    plugin.getConfig();
    plugin.getConfig().set("Database."+player.getName()+".Level", nextlevel);
    plugin.saveConfig();
}
```

Comment: You should attach a debugger (e.g. Eclipse), set a breakpoint on the line in question, and step through it while looking at the values of your variables.  The problem should be very obvious at that point.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse i'm using NetBeans , that code is "correct" according netbeans

Comment: That code *compiles* according to Netbeans; that doesn't make it *correct*, it just means it doesn't have any syntax errors.  Netbeans has a debugger as well; you should use it to step through this code, because it's a **really** useful skill.  You should do that as a learning opportunity even though I believe that the apparent copy-and-paste error I pointed out in my answer is probably the solution to your immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You set `int kills = plugin.getConfig().getInt("Database."+player.getName()+".Level");`
- You set `int level = plugin.getConfig().getInt("Database."+player.getName()+".Level");`, so `level == kills`.
- You set `int exp = (basicexp * level) + (incremento * level);`, so `exp == (basicexp + incremento) * level`, so `exp > level` if `(basicexp + increment) > 1`, which is likely.
- Since `kills == level`, then `exp > kills`, which means that it will never be true that `kills >= exp`.

Maybe you meant to get something other than ".Level" from the config when reading the value for `kills`?

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.  When I'm debugging, I usually try to work backwards.  I'll go to something that's not working (like your if statement), and look at the variables when I'm at that line.  If one of them isn't the value I expected, I'll look at how it got set (and maybe set an earlier breakpoint and re-run so I can watch it actually get set), and keep doing that till I find the code that's not doing the right thing.  It works for me, hopefully the same approach is useful for you...